# Implement Drag & Drop in Gingerbread

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, touch-event, viewgroup, onlongclicklistener

I need to know how I can implement Drag & Drop in Android for the Gingerbread version. As I know Gingerbread doesn't support that by default.

What I have coded: a `ViewGroup` class to hold dynamic added child, each child should after a long click
be able to get moved through a finger tap/move. To solve this, i have a `OnLongClickListener` attached to each `View`'s child and my `ViewGroup` have implemented both the methods `onTouch()` to get the down/up/move events and the method `onLongClick()` to response to the long click on each child.

Now my problem is as follows: I long tap a child, I can move it and can end the action through the `ACTION_UP` event. But, I can't long tap this child again - is there a way or library that can handle that?

I think, I don't need a really D&D library/function because I only will order some icons in this `ViewGroup` - each child gets added to the `ViewGroup` via code, so I don't have a really DropTarget I think.

Comment: i fixed the problem as follows:
1.) let each child have a new instance of OnLongClickListener, this prevents the parent to response to the LongClick event.
2.) return the correct values (true/false) in onTouch() event

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/drag-drop-for-android-gridview/) example may help you. This example has a complete drag and drop framework for pre 3.0. And also the feature you are requesting with "dragging a dropped child" as default.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the project at https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView. This code really helped me out.

Follow the `onLayout()` and the `onTouch()` in the `DraggableGridView` class. Let me know if this was/wasn't helpful. It's very similar to your situation in regards to `ViewGroup` and adding views.