# Android drag and drop for pre Honeycomb version

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop

So I am developing a drag and drop application in android using ClipData. But it's only for Honeycomb and above. How can I make a drag and drop app using ClipData for pre Honeycomb versions. Do you have any idea? or Has anybody here already tried it? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802969/implement-drag-drop-in-gingerbread

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete tutorial on how drag-drop can be implemented for pre-HoneyComb versions.

[Drag-Drop for pre-Honeycomb version](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/moving-views-part-3/)

Comment: Hello, I need to get the same absolute location of dragged object to its drop zone.

Comment: I guess that should be a separate question, with some relevant code showing what you have tried with some more details!